How to store landing page URL in existing logic for tracking UTM parameters?
I'm working on a function that tracks UTM parameters and source details for users visiting my website. The function retrieves UTM source, term, and campaign from the request object and stores them in the session if they are new.
Here's the relevant part of the code:
$utmSources = session('source_details') ?? [];
$utmSources = collect($utmSources);
$x = [];

if (count($utmSources) == 0) {
    $id = count($utmSources) + 1;
    $currentTimeUTC = now()->utc()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $x = [
        'id' => $id,
        'source_tag' => 'utm',
        'source_value' => Session::get('source_value'),
        'time' => $currentTimeUTC,
    ];

    $sources = !empty($x) ? $utmSources->add($x) : $utmSources;

    Session::put('source_details' , $sources);
} else {
    $lastElement = $utmSources->last();
    $sourceValue = $lastElement['source_value'];

    if (($sourceValue != $utmSource && $utmSource != null)) {
        $id = count($utmSources) + 1;
        $currentTimeUTC = now()->utc()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $x = [
            'id' => $id,
            'source_tag' => 'utm',
            'source_value' => $utmSource,
            'time' => $currentTimeUTC,
        ];

        $sources = !empty($x) ? $utmSources->add($x) : $utmSources;

        Session::put('source_details' , $sources);
    }
}

I'd like to store the landing page URL along with the UTM parameters. Where's the best place to insert the logic to store the landing page URL within this code snippet?

What is your definition of "landing page"? If you simply mean the first URL the user visits, within their current session - then you should insert the current URL, at the moment you realize you have not stored any landing page URL yet.

$sources = !empty($x) ? ... - how could it possibly be empty, when you explicitly assigned a non-empty array to the variable right before this?
